# Hard-Coding a Form so User Can't Edit It

Tags: php, html

I would like to hard-code the form below.  In other words, I would like to post $submission and $fullurl to index.php as "tweet" without giving the user the option to edit them.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**  I want the user to still click a button that says "Tweet" to post the variables.

Thanks in advance,

John

```
<form method='post' action='index.php'>

<br />

<textarea  name="tweet" cols="50" rows="5" id="tweet" ><?php echo $submission ?> <?php echo $fullurl ?></textarea>

<br />

<input type='submit' value='Tweet' name='submit' id='submit' />

</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form method='post' action='index.php'>

<p><?php echo $submission ?> <?php echo $fullurl ?></p>

<input type="hidden" name="tweet" value="<?php echo $submission ?> <?php echo $fullurl ?>">

<input type='submit' value='Tweet' name='submit' id='submit' />

</form>
```

That still doesn't mean the user won't be able to doctor the value through, everything's editable client-side one way or another. Save the to-be-submitted tweet server-side in a session if you need absolutely immutable values.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make it completely invisible (`style="visibility:hidden"`), or disable it (`disabled="true"').

You can also just use `document.getElementById('formID').submit();` to submit the form automatically.

Better yet, just make them all hidden inputs, and submit on page load with the above code.

Comment: That's easily editable with chrome's Webkit Inspector or firebug

Comment: if you disable it then it won't post

Comment: If something is done client-side, it **can always be modified** before being submitted. Don't trust the user.

Comment: Yes, that is a given with javascript; but he is asking for a way to do it using javascript, and the above is the way I would do it.  If he were to give a more generalized situation (instead of asking how to make this work, he asks what he should do to make this work) I could give some better answers.

Comment: Show me where he asks for javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but it sounds like you just want to have some variables kept serverside without a user being able to edit them, between page loads.

In that case you may wish to learn about [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and session variables. These allow you to store stuff in between page loads without a user being able to edit them (but you can still read from them so you can display your variables on the page!)

If you could perhaps rephrase your question some if this isn't the answer you are looking for, we would be better able to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

- You could set the `disabled`
  attribute of the `<textarea>`. But then
  it would not be submitted with the
  form. So you'd have to make a hidden
  input with the value or use sessions to persist the data if it could not be recreated therwise.
- You could also use JavaScript to blur the text area on focus. But there are ways around this, i.e. disable JavaScript.

In the end, I think you should reconsider the user interface and user experience. A textarea that isn't editable, probably should be a form element. Just display the data you plan to tweet and allow them to *Appove* it.

Comment: Agreed, much better approach, he might find it better to use php's curl library.